# python script doesn't write a word in a text file after launching through another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dear stackoverflow community,
I need some help at a little AI Testing-programm I wanted to make as a school project.

The problem is that if I launch a python file through another python file, the file that should be launching isn't writing anything in a .txt file. However if I launch that one file that isn't writing anything trough the console it suprisingly writes its entry and does what it should do. Could someone pls tell me why the one program doesn't write anything, when I launch it with the other program? I've already disabled my Antivirus(AVG) but that didn't help.

Here's my code:

The one program that is launching the other program, which doesn't write anything:

```
    import os
    import random
    import time
    for i in range(1):
        file = open('INPUT.txt','w')
        x=random.randint(1,3)
        if x==1:
            file.write("gelb")
            GesuchtesWort="Banane"
        elif x==2:
            file.write("rot")
            GesuchtesWort="Erdbeere"
        else:
            file.write("orange")
            GesuchtesWort="Orange"
        file.close()

        os.system('E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')
        time.sleep(1)

        file = open('RESULT.txt','r')
        if GesuchtesWort!=str(file.read()):
            file.close()
            file = open('MARK.txt','w')
            file.write("0")
        else:
            file.close()
            file = open('MARK.txt','w')
            file.write("1")
        file.close()

The one program that just writes through console:

import random
class InputLayer:
    def InputN1(string):
        Output=0
        x=0

        LetterList=[]
        for i in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            LetterList.append(i)

        for i in string:
            x=x+1
            Output+=LetterList.index(i)*x
        return Output

class HiddenLayer:
    def HiddenN1(number,boolean):
        file = open('ChangingValue1.txt','r+')
        ChangingValue=float(file.read())
        Output=1/(1+number)
        if boolean and (Output>=ChangingValue):
            return Output
        elif boolean==False:
            x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)
            while x==0:
                x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)
            ChangingValue+=x
            #Eintrag
            file.seek(0)
            file.write(str(ChangingValue))
            file.close()


    def HiddenN2(number,boolean):
        file = open('ChangingValue2.txt','r+')
        ChangingValue=float(file.read())
        Output=1/(1+number)
        if boolean and (Output>=ChangingValue):
            return Output
        elif boolean==False:
            x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)
            while x==0:
                x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)  
            ChangingValue+=x
            #Eintrag
            file.seek(0)
            file.write(str(ChangingValue))
            file.close()

    def HiddenN3(number,boolean):
        file = open('ChangingValue3.txt','r+')
        ChangingValue=float(file.read())
        Output=1/(1+number)
        if boolean and (Output>=ChangingValue):
            return Output
        elif boolean==False:
            x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)
            while x==0:
                x=(random.randint(-1,1)/1000)
            ChangingValue+=x
            #Eintrag
            file.seek(0)
            file.write(str(ChangingValue))
            file.close()

class OutputLayer:
    def OutputN1(number):
        if number>0.5:
            return "Banane"
        elif number>0 and number<0.5:
            return "Erdbeere"
        else:
            return "Orange"

#print(InputLayer.InputN1("lefpA"))
#file = open('ChangingValue1.txt','r+')
#x=file.read()
#print(x)
#file.seek(0)
#file.write(str(5))
#file.close()

#Main

#gelb|rot|orange
file=open('INPUT.txt','r')
UserInput=str(file.read())
file.close()

Layer1Output = InputLayer.InputN1(UserInput)
num1=HiddenLayer.HiddenN1(Layer1Output,True)
num2=HiddenLayer.HiddenN2(Layer1Output,True)
num3=HiddenLayer.HiddenN3(Layer1Output,True)
print(str(num1)+","+str(num2)+","+str(num3))
file = open('RESULT.txt','w')
file.write(OutputLayer.OutputN1(num1+num2+num3))
print(OutputLayer.OutputN1(num1+num2+num3))
file.close()

file = open('MARK.txt','r')
if str(file.read())=="0":
    HiddenLayer.HiddenN1(Layer1Output,False)
    HiddenLayer.HiddenN2(Layer1Output,False)
    HiddenLayer.HiddenN3(Layer1Output,False)
file.close()
```

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your code down to just the relevant parts (a simple script that runs another script, which writes a string to a file) and see if it works then. If it does work, then slowly build it up to what you have now and see where it breaks. That will give you a clue to what the problem is. If it doesn't work, then post _that_ to Stack Overflow. You aren't supposed to post full programs like this here.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that

Comment: For some reason it works when I use the command os.system('AI_Test.py 1') instead of os.system('E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')...

Comment: Ah... That is your clue! So, it doesn't like the full path, and I see why. Look at what happens when you do `print('E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')`. You don't get "E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py" printed to the screen. That's because "\" is a special character in python strings. You need to either escape it with an extra "\" (i.e. use `'E:\\7B\\Informatik\\Schlifelner\\raspberry\\AI_Test.py'` instead) or, even better, prefix the whole string with an 'r' to use a 'raw' string (i.e. use `r'E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py'`)

Comment: Ah ok didn’t know that thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
os.system('E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')
```

As an experiment, look at what happens when you use `print` instead of `os.system`:

```
>>> print('E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')
aspberry\AI_Test.pyifelner
```

You don't get "E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py" printed to the screen. That's because "\" is a special character in python strings, so all the characters following those "\" characters (in particular, the "\r", which is a carriage return) are not doing what you think.

You need to either escape all of the "\" characters:

```
>>> print('E:\\7B\\Informatik\\Schlifelner\\raspberry\\AI_Test.py')
E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py
```

Or, even better, prefix the whole string with an 'r' to use a 'raw' string:

```
>>> print(r'E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')
E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py
```

So you need to just change that one line to:

```
os.system(r'E:\7B\Informatik\Schlifelner\raspberry\AI_Test.py')
```

(note the 'r' before the string)